# Condition Where count number of shifts

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a table "rota" where volunteers submit the shifts they are available. They can submit more than 6 shifts, but 6 is the minimum required.

I want to see how many volunteers have selected each of the shifts, but I want to see only those who have selected 6 shifts.

I am running a wrong SQL, but can-t figure it out what I am doing wrong:

```
SELECT COUNT(volunteer_id), shift_id 
FROM rota 
GROUP BY shift_id 
WHERE COUNT(shift_id = 6);
```

EDIT:
I wrongly explained what I was trying to do.

I want to see how many volunteers have selected each of the shifts, but I want to see only those shifts who have been selected by volunteers who submitted only 6 shifts. Does it make sense?

EDIT:

Tried this but not working:

```
SELECT COUNT(volunteer_id), shift_id 
FROM rota
WHERE volunteer_id IN (SELECT volunteer_id FROM rota
GROUP BY volunteer_id HAVING COUNT DISTINCT(shift_id) = 6)
GROUP BY shift_id;
```

Comment: You should add sample data to your question.

Comment: I have 30 different "shift_id" and 100 different "volunteer_id".
Volunteers can submit a minimum of 6 shifts and a maximum of 20. I just want to see only the shifts of "shift_id" selected by the volunteers of "volunteer_id" who have submitted just 6 shifts.

Comment: Sorry Tim, pretty new here. How can I do that?

Comment: I updated my answer, if it might help you.

Answer (score 2):

You can try below -

```
SELECT volunteer_id,COUNT(shift_id )
FROM rota 
GROUP BY volunteer_id
having COUNT(shift_id )= 6
```

Comment: Column 'shift_id ' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @MukeshKalgude, that column was mistakenly there, only for this you down voted me?

Comment: This code displays the volunteers who have submitted 6 shifts, but I have explained it wrongly. Please, see the edit above.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT COUNT(volunteer_id), shift_id 
FROM rota
WHERE volunteer_id IN (SELECT volunteer_id FROM rota
                       GROUP BY volunteer_id HAVING (COUNT DISTINCT shift_id) = 6)
GROUP BY shift_id 
HAVING COUNT(volunteer_id) = 6;
```

Assertions which take place *after* `GROUP BY` has happened need to appear in a `HAVING` clause.  `HAVING` operates on *groups* of records.  The `WHERE` clause, on the other hand, is evaluated *before* `GROUP BY`, and operates on individual records.

Comment: Many thanks, but I have explained it wrongly. Please, see the edit above and hope it makes sense.